# Error deserializing a json when an array is empty

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to deserialize a json but when the array ("groups") is empty it gives me an error. How can I check in Unity that if there is no data in the "groups" field a message will appear, for example?

This is the error:

InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
BC_Equipos.successCallbackGMGI (System.String jsonResponse, System.Object cbObject) (at Assets/_AG/Scripts/BC_Equipos.cs:249)

The error line 249 is: var groups = (Dictionary<string, object>[])jsonData["groups"];

When there is data in "groups" all works fine.

The json is:

```
{
  "data": {
    "requested": [],
    "invited": [],
    "groups": []
  },
  "status": 200
}
```

Here is how I'm deserializating:

```
var jsonMessage = (Dictionary<string, object>)BrainCloud.JsonFx.Json.JsonReader.Deserialize(jsonResponse);
var jsonData = (Dictionary<string, object>)jsonMessage["data"];
var groups = (Dictionary<string, object>[])jsonData["groups"];

if (groups.Length > 0)
{
    Debug.Log("Groups List");

    foreach (var group in groups)
    {
        var groupId = group["groupId"];
        Debug.Log("groupId: " + groupId);

        var nameGroup = group["name"];
        Debug.Log("nameGroup: " + nameGroup);
    }
}
else
{
    Debug.Log("User hasn't joined a group already!");
}
```

Comment: Can you try this? `jsonData["groups"] as Dictionary<string, object[]>` Then it should return null when the cast is invalid, and not throw an exception. Otherwise, you can just wrap it in try-catch block and print a message on getting InvalidCastException.

Comment: You need a proper class then you do `JsonReader.Deserialize<YourRootObjectClass>(...`

Comment: @MarcGravell when I use "var groups = (Dictionary<string, object>[])jsonData["groups"];" and there are one or several groups in the json it works fine. The error appears when there is no groups.

Answer (score 0):

If the array is empty, the tool can't infer what kind of array to create - typical data in the general case could, after all, be `["abc", "def"]`, `[12, 42, 42]`, or - as seems to be the case - `[{ }, { }]`. It could even be something hybrid like `["abc", 42, {}]`. You may have better luck just casting to `Array` - or perhaps `object[]`, checking the length, and going from there. If `object[]` doesn't work: try `Array`, `IList`, or similar.

Or: a much better approach is to create a type model, and deserialize into *that*; then the serializer can use the defined model to interpret the data. For example:

```cs
public class SomeRoot {
    public SomeData data {get;set;}
    public int status {get;set;}
}
public class SomeData {
    public List<Request> requested {get;} = new();
    public List<Invite> invited {get;} = new();
    public List<Group> groups {get;} = new();
}
public class Request {}
public class Invite {}
public class Group {}
```